# Custom Request for Form Validations

Tags: php, laravel, forms, request

I'm facing a problem with custom request. I have created a request with `php artisan make:request StoreNewClient`.

I have configured the validations logic inside the new request file, like:

```php
namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class StoreNewClient extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return Auth::check();
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [ ...
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Get the error messages for the defined validation rules.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function messages()
    {
        return [ ...
        ];
    }
}
```

In the controller, I imported the file like `use App\Http\Requests\StoreNewClient;` and after, In the function store() I writed:

```php
public function store(StoreNewClient $request)
{
// Will return only validated data        
$validated = $request->validated();

...
}
```

That what I understood from the documentation, but this give me an error: `Class App\Http\Requests\StoreNewClient does not exist` but exists (!!).

I already tried to clear caches and dumped the composer but didn't solved the problem. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Fount the error. In the messages(), 1 line didn't had the comma at the end and neither the app neither the composer dump-autoload, gave any error.